# CSS : Drop down navigation menu visited

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In the following code, when I'm hovering **dropdown #1 item #1** the hover effect of **dropdown #1 item #1** goes off, where I need to make it stay until I'm out of that menu item and sub items of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kLDrG/

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navmenu.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item #1</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">item #2</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">item #3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
</div>
<!-- Nav end -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS File

```
#body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#nav {

}
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ffb108;

}

#nav ul li a{
    color: #ffb108;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:visited{

    color:#FFF;

    }

#nav ul li a:hover{

    color:#FFF;

    }


#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:  #ffb108;

    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a{
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Didn't get it. You have `#nav ul ul li a:hover {color: #333;}` which is black. Do you want to change this?

Comment: @Alek I have included JSFiddle file,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
#nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This styles the a tag within the hovered li. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have the :hover that changes the color applied to the `<a>`, not the `<li>`.
You should have a hover on the `<li>` style the `<a>` and it will work correctly.
CSS:

```
#nav ul li:hover a{

    color:#FFF;

    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/kLDrG/4/)